# How to get the value of dynamically populated input ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a textarea that has been dynamically populated,

```
<textarea class="materialize-textarea validate addCommentTxt" 
value="" data-length="250" required  name="addCommentTxt"></textarea>
```

My problem is that whenever I try to get the value of the textarea in ajax, with this code:

```
$('.btnCommentSubmit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var comment_identifier = $(this).data("value");
    var comment_by = $(this).data("id");
    $('#formAddComment').attr('action', '<?php echo base_url() ?>Discussion/addComment/');
    var url = $('#formAddComment').attr('action');
    var addCommentTxt = $('.addCommentTxt').val(); //GET THE VALUE OF TEXT AREA
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: url,
        data: {
            addCommentTxt:addCommentTxt,
            comment_identifier:comment_identifier,
            comment_by:comment_by,
        },
        success: function(){
            alert("scs");
            showAllComments(comment_identifier);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log(data);
            alert('Could not add data');
        }
    });

});
```

The value that I get is from the first populated textarea, not from the textarea that I sent my data.

For example:
Textarea 1 - I have sent a "first String" comment and it has been inserted successfully.

Textarea 2 - I have sent a "second String" comment, but the inserted data will be "first String" which is from the textarea 1 not in the textarea 2

Comment: So what will i use to get the value of input? I already tried using class.

Comment: can you provide the rest of your html?

Comment: you need to get the `addCommentTxt` relative to your `btnCommentSubmit`

Comment: `$('.addCommentTxt').val()` this will always get the value of first element with class addCommentTxt

Comment: It is long, but i'll  post it in jsfiddle, i put a @GO HERE marker so that you'll find that section easily.

<br>

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lw0cakdp/1/

Comment: @madalinivascu sorry i didn't understand what you've said.

Comment: @SKJajoriya Yes, that is my problem

Comment: @ANGELOJR.GANADEN see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the `addCommentTxt` relative to your `btnCommentSubmit` so use closest to get your parent form and then use find to get the textarea value

```
var addCommentTxt = $(this).closest('form').find('.addCommentTxt').val();
```

Comment: It doesn't work, anyways here is the whole row, incase you want it
https://jsfiddle.net/aLdu2mce/

Comment: I tried using alert to display the value and it return undefined.

Comment: works for me https://jsfiddle.net/aLdu2mce/3/ , what errors do you have in the console?